# I have a old question. What is the law that says the military will not be formed inless a abuse befalls a United States of America American?

Tags: constitutional-law, military

I have a old question. What is the law that says the United States of America will not have a formed military and the United States of America Military will not gather, congregate or group unless an abuse befalls a United States of America American and at which time the United States of America Military will only from a court to determine if the abuse is severe enough to from the whole and complete United States of America Military forces?

Answer (score 7):

There is no such law. The [US Constitution](https://www.senate.gov/civics/constitution_item/constitution.htm) provides that:

> The President shall be Commander in Chief of the Army and Navy of the United States, and of the Militia of the several States, when called into the actual Service of the United States; (Article II section 2)
>
> The congress shall have the power (Article I section 8)
>   ...
>
> To declare War, grant Letters of Marque and Reprisal, and make Rules concerning Captures on Land and Water;
>
> To raise and support Armies, but no Appropriation of Money to that Use shall be for a longer Term than two Years;
>
> To provide and maintain a Navy;
>
> To make Rules for the Government and Regulation of the land and naval Forces;
>
> To provide for calling forth the Militia to execute the Laws of the Union, suppress Insurrections and repel Invasions;
>
> To provide for organizing, arming, and disciplining, the Militia, and for governing such Part of them as may be employed in the Service of the United States, reserving to the States respectively, the Appointment of the Officers, and the Authority of training the Militia according to the discipline prescribed by Congress;

These powers were used to create the military very early in the history of the United States, and the US Army and US Navy have existed ever since. Other branches of the military were created later.